# BeautifulSoup object not matching a website's html markup in chrome's DeveloperTools

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am tring to crawl this [link](http://www.sears.com/appliances-refrigerators-french-door-refrigerators/b-1031416) using Python's BeautifulSoup and urllib2 libraries. One problem that I am running into is that the soup object does not match the webpage's html shown using GoogleChrome's DeveloperTool. I checked multiple times and I am certain that I am passing the correct address. The reason I know they are different is because I printed the entire soup object onto sublime2 and compared it against what is shown on chrome's DeveloperTools. I also searched for really specific tags in the soup object. After debugging for hours, I am out of ideas. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there some sort of re-direction that is going on?

Comment: Please share the code what have you tried

Comment: This is because there is so much more happening on the browser side to construct the page. `urllib2` would only get you the initial html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript will be run in the website which changes the website DOM. Any url library (such as urllib2) only downloads the HTML and does not execute included/linked JavaScript. That's why you see a difference.